# I can't delete artboards in the current version of Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I tried researching and can't find answers.

I made 6 artboards, I was able to delete the second 3 artboards I made, but I can't delete the first three. Thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, you were able to delete the 3 bottom Artboards but you cannot delete the 3 top Artboards? You do have to at least have 1 Artboard in the file. If you make a new file, are you able to delete Artboards? Do you have layers that are locked or Artboards that could be locked?

Comment: I have few layers that are locked on these artboards and these layers are the culprit. Thank you for mentioning this. I just solved my problem!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I have locked layers on these artboards that I can't delete and those are the ones preventing me to delete them.

Comment: Don't forget to choose your own answer as best!